# Multiindex categorization and encoding this in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, multi-index

I have multiindex mapping rules, here's the rules

```
Type A: Chicken, Beef, Goat
Type B: Fish, Shrimp
Type C: Chicken, Pork
```

I here's my dataframe, let say this is a `df` dataframe, and want to do multi index mapping

```
   id   Menu
   1    Fried Chicken
   2    Shrimp Chips
   3    Pork with Cheese
   4    Fish Spaghetti
   5    Goat Sate
   6    Beef Soup
```

With `pandas`, it can be use `pd.MultiIndex` and `pd.Series.str.get_dummies`. So, the code will be

```
from pandas import pd
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

m = {
    'Type A': ['Chicken', 'Beef', 'Goat'],
    'Type B': ['Fish', 'Shrimp'],
    'Type C': ['Chicken', 'Pork']
}

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(k, v) for k, values in m.items() for v in values])

df.join(
    df.Menu.str.get_dummies(sep=' ') \
      .reindex(columns=mux, level=1).max(axis=1
, level=0)
)
```

The output would be like this

```
 id     Menu                 Type A   Type B   Type C
   1    Fried Chicken        1        0        1
   2    Shrimp Chips         0        1        0
   3    Pork with Cheese     0        0        1
   4    Fish Spaghetti       0        1        0
   5    Goat Sate            1        0        0
   6    Beef Soup            1        0        0
```

How to do this on pySpark datafarame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard multi-indexing in spark.

What you can do is check if your string contains any of your elements :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

index_dict = {
    'Type A': ['Chicken', 'Beef', 'Goat'],
    'Type B': ['Fish', 'Shrimp'],
    'Type C': ['Chicken', 'Pork']
}

for col_name, values in index_dict.items():
    col = F.col('Menu').like('%'+values[0]+'%')
    for value in values[1:]:
        col2 = F.col('Menu').like('%'+value+'%')
        col = col | col2
    df = df.withColumn(col_name, col)
```

I think it could be faster if you don't check the whole string when you know the separator. You could therefore use :

`df = df.withColumn('tmp', F.split(df['Menu'], ' '))`

Replace `F.col('Menu').like('%'...'%')` with `F.array_contains(F.col('tmp'), ...)`

And finish with `df = df.drop('tmp')`

Comment: Error on the last line `AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'withColumn'`

Comment: You're not using a `'DataFrame'` object but a `'PipelinedRDD'`. Can you convert it to a Spark DataFrame ? http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame

Comment: It works, your output in boolean, not in number

header  `id     Menu                  Type A   Type B   Type C` and frist column
 `1    Fried Chicken    true        false      true`

But, you deserve best answer

Comment: Yes, which was useful to my mind. Then do `from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType` and change `df = df.withColumn(col_name, col)` to `df = df.withColumn(col_name, col.cast(IntegerType))`

Comment: already try las comment,  the error `unexpected type: <class 'type'>`, I guess it better to ask in new question, to show all the error, but now is 10.30 pm in Indonesia, will ask tomorrow

Comment: Yes indeed, it's my fault : it must be `df = df.withColumn(col_name, col.cast(IntegerType()))` (an instance of the class)

Comment: The last output is only cast 1 column only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177999/discussion-between-arius-and-nabih-bawazir).